# How to interpret number of messages in Distributor's Storage and Control queues?

Tags: nservicebus, nservicebus-distributor

This article tells about control queues Nsb Master node uses to control message load, though to me it's still not clear how to interpret disproportions in number of messages in this queues: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/msmq/distributor/

I'm observing slowness in my Nsb service which have never experienced slowness before. For some reason less parallel threads are created per every master node comparing to the past time, and there have been no change in workers or master nodes configuration, like max amount of threads to allocate. I'm trying to figure out if it's Master node that does not want to feed workers, or workers do not want to take more job.

I see that amount of messages in control queue jumps from 15 to 40, while storage has only 5-8. Should I interpret that as workers ready to work, while Distributor can't send them more messages? Thanks

Comment: How do you know that there are less parallel threads created on the workers, BTW? Conclusion based on the reduced throughput or did you check with Task Manager?

Comment: we have our own monitoring system. Every handler saves information about message arrival into a monitoring system storage, and then we display it in charts. This way we can see how many messages are received per minute per every worker. Before it managed to handle 4-5 times more messages per minute

Comment: Do you also have the ability to see trends on the average/max/min handling time of each message on the workers? If that average has gone up, it points to the business logic inside the handler being slower than before. If it is the same as before, it could point to the distributor sending messages at a slower rate..

Comment: that's the problem: we do not have this metric. It's easy to add, but anyway nothing to compare with unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

The numbers in the control and `storage queue` will jump up and down as long as the distributor is handing out messages. A message coming into the `control queue` will immediately be popped off that queue and onto the `storage queue`. A message coming into the `primary queue` of the distributor will immediately result in the first message of the `storage queue` to be popped off.
It's hard to interpret the numbers of messages in the queues of a running distributor, because, by the time you look at the numbers with Computer Management or Queue Explorer, they will have changed.

The extreme cases are this:

**1. No messages in the primary input queue of the distributor and no work happening on any of the workers.**

- Input queue: 0
- Control queue: 0
- Storage queue: number of workers*configured threads per worker

**2.  All workers are working at full capacity. None able to take on more work.**

- Input queue: 0+ (grows as new messages comes in)
- Control queue: 0
- Storage queue: 0

In a running system, it can be anything between these two extremes, so, unfortunately, it's hard to say much from just a snapshot of the `control` and `storage queue`.

Some troubleshooting tips:

- If the `storage queue` is empty, the distributor can not hand out more work. It does not know where to send it. This happens if all the workers are fully occupied as they will not be sending any ready-messages back to the `control queue` until they finish up handling a message.
- If the `storage queue` is consistently small compared to the total number of worker threads across all the workers, you are approaching the total maximum capacity of your workers.
- I suggest you start looking at the logs of the workers and see if the work they are doing is taking longer than usual. Slower database/third party integration?
- Another thing to check is if there has been anything IO-heavy added to the machine hosting the distributor. If the distributor was already running at close to max capacity, adding extra IO might slow down MSMQ on the box, giving you worse throughput.

Comment: Thank you. That's all is useful information and good to know, though I still do not how to apply it to my situation. In my case amount of messages in control queue and storage queue varies, but if you watch it for a while, I'll notice the first one is usually 4 times bigger than the second (like 32 vs 8). You're saying it's hard to make any conclusion based on this information, right?